# how to fill List(Of Type)?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, list, types

I'm trying to validate a multidimensional array of inputs.  I need to verify data types before they're sent to a prepared statement.

I'm making a `Function` that can be used to check data types of a multidimensional array received from a `WebMethod` ajax call, taking a multidimensional array as a parameter and a list of `Type`s as another to check the columns against.

I'm trying to do, for example,

```
Dim columnTypes = New List(Of Type) from {Integer, Integer, String, String}
```

but Visual Studio 2010 keeps reporting `'.' expected`.

How can this be done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type literals needs to be wrapped into [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx):

```
Dim columnTypes = New List(Of Type) From {GetType(Integer), GetType(Integer),
                                          GetType(String), GetType(String)}
```