# conditionally check Type of values from a container of GetType()s

Tags: vb.net, types, compare, conditional-statements

I am filling a `List(Of Type)` as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557681/1382306) with for example

```
Dim columnTypes = New List(Of Type) From {GetType(Integer), GetType(Integer),
    GetType(String), GetType(String)}
```

I'd like to compare the `List` to actual `Type` keywords, for example `String` in pseudo:

```
If columnTypes(i) = String Then
    //do it because it's a String and not an Integer or Boolean or Object or...
```

How can the `Type`s in this `List` be determined conditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use it's string representation but:

```
If columnTypes(0) = GetType(String) Then
    Console.Write("I'm a string")
End If
```

or the other way

```
If columnTypes.Contains(GetType(String)) Then
    Console.Write("It contains a string")
End If
```

Type comparison works this way since NET framework 4, with previous versions use [`Is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx):

```
If columnTypes(0) Is GetType(String) Then
    Console.Write("I'm a string")
ElseIf columnTypes(0) Is GetType(Int32) Then
    Console.Write("I'm an integer")
End If
```